To get status from a function in azure function app using postman GET request
I've a function which is triggered through postman https://{function-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code={code} Now I 'm trying to get status of this function triggered I've enabled application insights getting telemetry logs.
I want a GET request API which I tried setting up as:
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{app-ID}/events/requests/{invocation-ID}
Have created API key and it's added in the header. but I'm facing:
404 Not found
{
"error": {
"message": "The requested path does not exist",
"code": "PathNotFoundError",
"correlationId": "random id"
}
}
My requirement is I just want to know whether it was failed or success

HttpTriggers are not long running. They should give a resonse quicky. If you do want to make a longer running process you might want to look into Durable Functions. They are meant to run longer.

I just want to read the success or failure of the triggered function for that instance

There should be a status code in the http response

@Paul, Do you want to check the status in Application Insights or Postman as available here.

@Pravallika KV yes I want it to print the status of the function on Postman in the body . Is there an API to do so ?

@Paul, please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

You can use below Rest API to get the status of an Azure function.
GET https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query?query={query}

I have created a C# Http Triggered Azure function App and linked to Application Insights.

Create an API key under Application Insights=>API Access:



Use below API to get the status of Azure function:

https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<APP_ID>/query?query=requests
| project
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where cloud_RoleName =~ '<functionapp_name>' and operation_Name =~ '<function_name>'


Use the generated API key(under API access) as header x-api-key

x-api-key: {API-key}

Response:
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "operation_Name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "success",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "resultCode",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cloud_RoleName",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "invocationId",
                    "type": "dynamic"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "Function1",
                    "True",
                    "200",
                    "functionapp0107",
                    "dac3963bXXX5e-a789-c8c87ebd825c"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}


